# Почему в конце каждой строки появляется None?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дано задание построить пирамиду, задавая число.
Например, если заданное число 3, то на выходе должно получиться:

```
1
12
123
```

Если 5, то:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Я осуществил решение таким образом:

```
n = int(input())


def pyr(n):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        print(j, end='')


for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(pyr(i))
```

И на выходе получил:

```
1None
12None
123None
1234None
12345None
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, откуда там None?

Comment: а зачем ты выводишь результат функции `pyr(i)` в строке `print(pyr(i))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def pyr(n):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        print(j, end='')
    print("")

n = int(input())

for i in range(1, n+1):
    pyr(i)
```

Не пытайтесь печатать непечатные выражения :) типа `pyr(i)` - они же ничего не возвращают...